# User Session crashes on vscode start

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I just did an System update & upgrade on my linux mint 20.3
Since this upgrade on startup of vscode all open applications close and I get logged out.

From the dpkg.log I can see that: linux-image-5.15.0-87 was installed.

Please tell me if you need any more specific information.

Edit: starting vscode via: code --disable-extensions works fine.